# Zend Framework UTF-8 Translation from csv - Missing first UTF-8 characters

Tags: zend-framework, csv, utf-8, translation

I'm working with Zend Framework. I have a csv file with translated strings english - czech.

Everything would be great but missing first UFT-8 characters.

For example:

Spanish;Španělsky - displays as panělsky,

Saves your time and money;Šetří váš čas a peníze - displays as etří váš čas a peníze.

Comment: happens only with the first char?

Answer (score 0):

You should surround every entry with double quotes `""` in the `.csv` files.